# Unable to style polygons in a WebGL Layer

Tags: openlayers

I'm following the OpenLayers example '[WebGL Vector Layer](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/webgl-vector-layer.html)', and am trying to simply specify a color fill to the polygons from my GeoJSON file but am unable to.

I believe the problem may reside in the commented @type line in the sample referring to a 'WebGLStyle', as seen below. I have been unable to find, import or add a WebGLStyle. My polygons only show up in a gray color.

Could someone provide a code snippet which will allow me to just apply a simple red color fill to my polygons?

Code from the OL example mentioned above:

```
/** @type {import('ol/style/webgl.js').WebGLStyle} */
const style = {
  'stroke-color': ['*', ['get', 'COLOR'], [220, 220, 220]],
  'stroke-width': 3,
  'stroke-offset': -1,
  'fill-color': ['*', ['get', 'COLOR'], [255, 255, 255, 0.6]],
};
```

My code to attempt to try and style polygons in red:

```
const sStyle = {
  'fill-color': [255, 0, 0],
};

class WebGLLayer extends Layer {
  createRenderer() {
    return new WebGLVectorLayerRenderer(this, {
      className: this.getClassName(),
      sStyle,
    });
  }
}

const polygonLayer = new WebGLLayer({
  > Then add vector source, etc.
```

Comment: Do your features have a property named `COLOR`?  If not they will default to stroke color `[220, 220, 220]` (gray) and fill color `[255, 255, 255, 0.6]` (semi-transparent white)

Comment: No, sorry, the Color property code was from the OL example. I've updated the question with my code. I know I'm likely doing something wrong. I've been able to style WebGL point layers successfully, but can't get this WebGL polygon layer to cooperate.

Comment: It is working here https://codesandbox.io/s/webgl-vector-layer-forked-ggzc4h?file=/main.js  The option name `style` must be used, not `sStyle`

Comment: Thanks alot, Mike. Looks like my issue is something else. I built a fresh OL install folder download from node and then tried just your reduced sample, and then the full original sample. No matter what layer I use, or how I style it, the ecoregions or my own polygons all show up in gray fill with white stroke.  My Chrome browser is up to date, and the sample on the OpenLayers.org site shows up fine, as does your sample sandbox, I see red there.  Still, anything I build locally from the npm node download doesn't seem to work.  Anything else I can try?  Thanks again.

Comment: So I tried a full reinstall today via "npm install ol" and the polygon issue is now fixed! Yes!  But now the WebGL point layers are now giving me errors. Ugh. I've tried lots of variations to no avail.  I'm using pretty much basic code from the samples.  The point layer errors I'm seeing are attached in the original issue description 12/2 note in "Errors" link. Thanks.

Comment: If you updated to a newer version the styles may have changed https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/changelog/upgrade-notes.md#change-of-the-symbol-style-format-in-ollayerwebglpointslayer

Comment: Thanks, Mike, that allowed me to get them to display again without errors. I've got some work to do to recreate the styling with the new pattern. One example, this earlier sample line allowed points to scale based upon zoom level: 
  size: ['interpolate', ['exponential', 2], ['zoom'], 0, 5, 20, 20]
Is there a snippet perhaps to recreate that capability with the new 'circle-radius'?
That upgrade notes doc you shared is super helpful, and I'll refer to those going forward. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: See https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/14837 for the exponential issue

Comment: Got it. Thanks again, Mike, you're a hero!

Answer (score 0):

With help from Mike's comments, determined that this code should work. Did a fresh install via "npm install ol" which remedied the issue.